# Remove HTML tags without specifying names by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

On JavaScript, it can remove all HTML tags in the text with regular expressions like this:

```
replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")
```

In addition, I would like to keep specific tags.

```
ex)<h1>Text</h1><input type="text">Text</input><b>Text</b> → <h1>Text</h1>Text<b>Text</b>
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
replace(/<\/{0,1}!(font|h\d|p|hr|pre|blockquote|ol|ul|...).*?>/ig, "");
```

Please let me know the best formula.

Comment: There's numerous posts around explaining that parsing (i.e., analyzing) HTML will not succeed with REs. Simple tasks, such as eliminating all markup, will work, but more complex stuff won't work. This is due to the simplicity of regular languages (strings described by REs), compared to the complexity of HTML. My first attempt would be to filter the DOM.

Comment: I'll use strip_tags for JavaScript. I appreciate everybody's reply.

Answer (score 1):

[**THE PONY HE COMES**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Especially in JavaScript, there is no excuse.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = your_input_here;
var allowedtags = "font|h[1-6]|p|hr|...";

var rgx = new RegExp("^(?:"+allowedtags+")$","i");
var tags = div.getElementsByTagName('*');
var length = tags.length;
var i;
for( i=length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if( !tags[i].nodeName.match(rgx)) {
        while(tags[i].firstChild) {
            tags[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tags[i].firstChild,tags[i]);
            // this will take all children and extract them
        }
        tags[i].parentNode.removeChild(tags[i]);
    }
}

var result = div.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use negative lookahead:

```
replace(/<\/?(?!(font|h[1234]|p|hr|input|pre|blockquote|ol|ul))[^>]*>/ig, "");
```

**Caution:** HTML parsing and manipulation is error prone using regex like this. Better to use DOM parsers.

Comment: I trid this regex, but some tags will remain.
<h1>Text</h1><input type="text">Text</input><b>Text</b>
→
<h1>Text<input type="text">Text<b>Text

Answer (score 0):

What about using such a simple function to remove unwanted tags:

```
function sanitize(text, allowed) {

    var tags = typeof allowed === 'string' ? allowed.split(',') : allowed;

    var a = document.createElement('div');
    a.innerHTML = text;

    for (var c = a.childNodes, i = c.length; i--;) {
        if (c[i].nodeType == 1) {
            c[i].innerHTML = sanitize(c[i].innerHTML, tags);
            if (tags.indexOf(c[i].tagName.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                c[i].parentNode.removeChild(c[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return a.innerHTML;
}

sanitize('<h1>This is a <script>alert(1)</script> test</h1> <input type="text"> and <b>this</b> should stay.', 'font,h1,h2,p,b,ul')
```

Output:

```
"<h1>This is a  test</h1>  and <b>this</b> should stay."
```

Or you can replace tag with it's text content if you use

```
c[i].parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(c[i].innerText);
```

instead of `c[i].parentNode.removeChild(c[i]);`